# Is there a way to implement this override?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-3.1

I have a Set of Classes that look like this.

```
Public Abstract Class ParentClass{
    Abstract Public ParentClass ParentClassObj { get; set; }
}

Public Class Child1Class{
}

Public Class Child2Class{
    Public Override Child1Class ParentClassObj { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting an error that the type of the overridden class doesn't match. Is there any way to override like this?

EDIT: (here is my actual code as per request, not that different from above)

```
namespace ClosedName.Models
{
    public abstract class CategoryBase : ModelBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        abstract public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
        abstract public CategoryBase ParentCategory { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ClosedName.Models
{
    public class ProductSubcategory : CategoryBase
    {
        [Required]
        public override int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
        public override ParentCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace ClosedName.Models
{
    public class ParentCategory : CategoryBase
    {
        public string ParentCategoryDescriptionEnum { get
            {
                return Description?.Replace(" ", "");
            } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your actual code?

Comment: If `Child1Class` and `Child2Class` both inherit from `ParentClass`, then this isn't possible, because only read-only properties can be covariant.

Comment: What Johnathan says, ... _but_ ... all of which could implement an interface to reflect the "has a parent object" property. Then it depends what you want to do while traversing that chain...

Answer (score 0):

Create generic class for subcategories instead of overriding

```
public Category
{
}

public SubCategory<TParent> : Category
    where TParent : Category
{
    public TParent ParentCategory { get; set; }
}

public ProductCategory : Category
{
}

public ProductSubcategory : SubCategory<ProductCategory>
{
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the specifics of my project. The comments above answered my question that it isn't possible